# screen not displaying in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have hese snippet for a login screen and these codes arent displaying when i launch the app on the android device

here the error on the console I/flutter (12389): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12389): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (12389): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (12389): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderAnimatedOpacity's layout() function by the
I/flutter (12389): following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserEmail extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return UserEmailState();
  }

}

class UserEmailState extends State<UserEmail> {

  final TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),

      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Welcome",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),),
                  Text("A short slogan about the app...")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        controller: _emailController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Email",
                          hintText: "Enter email address"
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: null,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: new Text(
                            "Continue")
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your TextField inside an Expanded or Flexible widget. Like this:

```
            Flexible(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _emailController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Email",
                            hintText: "Enter email address"
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```